# Windows 8 and installing from image (Norton Ghost/Macrium Reflect/etc)

Tags: windows-8, disk-image, norton-ghost, macrium

First of, I'm not sure if this fits here or should be in Server Fault. If it should be in Server Fault, please let me know and I will close here and repost there.

Now to my situation: I have 30 Windows 8 laptops that I need to set up with identical images (i.e. same software and settings on all of them). With Windows 7 this would have been an easy 3 step process: 
 1. Set up one laptop;
 2. create a hdd image with Macrium Reflect, Norton Ghost or some similar software;
 3. Deploy the image to the remaining machines and update their license keys

Step 3 was possible because OEM installs had the COA sticker on the back that conveniently provided the activation key. With Windows 8 the activation key is somehow baked into the bios. Hence my question: Has anyone come up with a solution that will accommodate for this?

I'm open to working with images or somehow cloning the settings and, more importantly, the installed software from box to box or anything else that keeps me from having to manually set up 30 individual systems.

Comment: Why not do it properly using Windows ADK/WAIK, sysprep and imagex instead of using all these third party imaging programs?

Comment: Looking into those now. Thank you very much for the pointers, if this addresses the problem with the license keys it would be brilliant!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "official" MS answer (as painful as it seems) is that you shouldn't be imaging from an OEM version source. Get a volume licence, as they include re-imaging rights.

One of the reasons for this is that you basically HAVE to use WAIK and SysPrep to pull off a proper image with Windows 8.  And if you're using an OEM image as your base, it's probably already had all (or most of) its SysPrep re-arms used up during the creation of the image by the OEM.

See MS' [Licensing Brief - Reimaging Rights](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/about-licensing/briefs/reimaging.aspx)

> OEM media may be used to ***individually*** recover an image to a device using recovery media provided by the OEM. The OEM recovery media (1) should match the product version that was originally preinstalled on the system, (2) **may only be used to image devices that came with it**, and (3) ***may not be modified prior to recovering an image to a device***.

The good news is that you only need one of these VL licenses to get the imaging rights, and as long as each of the computers you're imaging onto have an equivalent version of Windows and a legitimate OEM license (basically "Pro" is you choice), you can use the single equivalent VL key to key them all.

> You must purchase at least one license of the Microsoft software that you want to reimage under your Open License authorization number or Microsoft Open Value or Microsoft Open Value Subscription Agreement number. This purchase is required to obtain the media and necessary Volume Licensing Keys (VLK[s]). You may use this media to reimage as many devices as you have licenses for, subject to the reimaging eligibility requirements described above.
>
> ...you may use Volume Licensing media to reimage any device properly licensed to run what it is being reimaged with.

Comment: If you are going to use WADK and Sysprep, why not go all the way into the recommended route and use the Microsoft Deployment Toolkit (MDT)?

With MDT you could move away from using different images for each machine and application combination and towards a single image. MDT allows application installation and drivers to be managed separately from your deployment image.

See:
https://technet.microsoft.com/windows/dn481547 (Simple Walkthrough with Offline USB Stick Media)
https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn744280 (Detailed Walkthrough)